# JavaFX (OpenJFX) not letting me print

Tags: javafx, printing

My JavaFX program prepares and prints out a set of VBoxes.

This is ModPrintCycle. It is the Window that gives the options to print

```
public PrintCycle data;
    //PrintCycle is a HashMap of VBoxes containing all the details
PrinterJob pj;
ChoiceBox<String> cbxPrinters = new ChoiceBox<String>();
ArrayList<Printer> arrPrinters = new ArrayList<Printer>();

//util.say just pops out a messagebox attached to ModPrintCycle.

public void printAll(ArrayList<String> pageList){
    if(cbxPrinters.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex() >=0){
        if (data.tables.size() > 0){
            Printer curP = Printer.getDefaultPrinter();
                if(arrPrinters.size() > 0 ){
                    curP = arrPrinters.get(cbxPrinters.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex());
                }
                try{
                    pj = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob(curP);
                    PageLayout pp = curP.createPageLayout(Paper.LEGAL, PageOrientation.PORTRAIT, MarginType.DEFAULT);
                    PageLayout pl = curP.createPageLayout(Paper.LEGAL, PageOrientation.LANDSCAPE, MarginType.DEFAULT);

                    for(String p : pageList){
                        Printable pt = data.tables.get(p);
                        pt.scaleToFit();
                        if(pt.isLandscape()){
                            pj.printPage(pl,pt);    
                        }
                        else{
                            pj.printPage(pp,pt);
                        }   
                    }

                    pj.endJob();
                }catch(Exception e){
                    util.say(ModPrintCycle.this, "Error on Print"); 
                }   
        }else{
            util.say(ModPrintCycle.this, "Nothing to print");
        }
    }
    else{
        util.say(ModPrintCycle.this, "No Printer Selected");
    }
}
```

Printer is installed and set as default, and my program detects it. But when I print, no errors pop out, and the printer receives no jobs.

I'm sure my program worked before (A Lubuntu 15.10, 32-bit.). But now, I transfered it to a different computer. A Lubuntu 15.10, 64-bit. I have openjfx and openjdk version "1.8.0_66-internal" installed.

What can I do to find out why it's not printing?

---

Tried to make a smaller print job, but to the same effect.

```
Button testPrint = new Button("Test Print");

    testPrint.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
            try{
                Printer p = Printer.getDefaultPrinter();
                PrinterJob pj = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob(p);
                //util.say(ModShortcuts.this, "Print: " + pj.getJobStatus());
                Boolean k = pj.printPage(p.createPageLayout(Paper.LEGAL,PageOrientation.PORTRAIT,MarginType.DEFAULT), new Text("Hey"));
                //util.password(); //reused for a showAndWait() dialog
                //util.say(ModShortcuts.this, "Print: " + pj.getJobStatus());
                //util.say(ModShortcuts.this, "attempted Print using: " + pj.getPrinter().getName());


                if(k){
                    //util.say(ModShortcuts.this, "Print: " + pj.getJobStatus());
                    pj.endJob();
                    //util.say(ModShortcuts.this, "Print: " + pj.getJobStatus());
                }

            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    });

    vbox.getChildren().add(testPrint);
```

Uncommented, the output is

```
Print: Not Printing
Print: Printing
attempted Print using: AstinePrinter
Print: Printing
Print: Done
```

AstinePrinter is the name of my printer.

---

Edit: Using

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

I installed Oracle Java 8, and still the same problem.

Edit: Also Oracle Java 7.

Edit:

Tried disabling the firewall, in case it was a port problem

```
sudo ufw disable
```

Still nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found something called ***CUPS4J***, and it allows me to bypass the problem it had concerning Java trying to access CUPS in a 64 bit Ubuntu. It prints out using Byte arrays, and luckily, JavaFX has a way to snapshot the chosen node.

It's a little blurry, but it's good enough. ***NOTE: I am no expert, and I don't know why this is needed. But doing this allowed me to use CUPS4J with no errors, so it must have been correct.***

- So, first of all, download the [[ECLIPSE PROJECT]](http://www.cups4j.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=2&Itemid=7) for `cups4j`,
  because there are dependencies that have to be fixed. Import it into your project.

EDIT: The reason why the following is needed is that somehow, my package doesn't come with `org.slf4j`. If your class path says you have it, skip these steps.

- Next, for each class there, all instances of `Logger` (cAsE
  sEnSiTiVe) should be replaced with `Log`, and fix your imports (Ctrl+Shift+O). This will suggest a version of the `Log`, and `LogFactory` will be automatically detected. My import path says `org.apache.commons.logging.*`
- Finally, remove the library dependency for `org.slf4j` in your build path under Libraries.

(I'm sure using the Runnable Jar is fine, but this is what I did because using the Runnable Jar gave me errors)

This is a simplification of what I did for my print function.

```
private void print(Region node){
    //Make the image with the proper sizes
    WritableImage wi = new WritableImage(
            (int) Math.round(Math.ceil(node.getWidth())),
            (int) Math.round(Math.ceil(node.getHeight())));
    //shoot the image
    wi = node.snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(), wi);

    //write the image into a readable context
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try{
        ImageIO.write(SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(wi, null), "png", out);  
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error with SnapShot function");
    }

    //Get your printer
    CupsClient cc = new CupsClient();
    CupsPrinter cp = cc.getDefaultPrinter();

    //print the readable context
    cp.print(new PrintJob.Builder(out.toByteArray()).build());

    //unlike PrinterJob, you do not need to end it.
}
```

I'm not sure, but I've seen bug reports in the CUPS4J forum saying there's a problem with multiple pages, but I have yet to encounter that.

If someone has a better answer, feel free to add. But so far, this worked for me.